# setting position to absolute and top to 0 in css causing javascript classList.toggle() to not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, navbar

I'm using the following javascript function to toggle a nav menu:

```
var navList = document.getElementById("navbar-list-landing");
var openBtn = document.getElementById("nav-open-landing");

function toggleNav() {
  navList.classList.toggle("open");
}
```

It works fine until I add the following CSS to the id of the ul I'm trying to hide:

```
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
```

The javascript function then will not run at all (using a console.log at the beginning of the function).

I'm including a code snippet of the entire nav below (stripped of all but the necessary CSS so it's a little ugly).

```js
var navList = document.getElementById("navbar-list-landing");
var openBtn = document.getElementById("nav-open-landing");

function toggleNav() {
  console.log("test");
  navList.classList.toggle("open");
}
```

```css
#nav-landing {
  position: fixed;
  background: #fff;
  height: 82px;
  width: 100%;
}
#nav-landing #nav-logo-landing {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
}
#nav-landing #navbar-list-landing {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#nav-landing #dropdown-more {
  display: none;
}
#nav-landing #nav-open {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#nav-landing .open {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav clearfix" id="nav-landing">

  <img src="./img/lenus-logo.png" alt="Lenus Logo" id="nav-logo-landing" />
  <a href="#" id="nav-open-landing" onclick="toggleNav()">=</a>

  <ul class="navbar-list" id="navbar-list-landing">
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">Services</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">Macra</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">Schedule a Consult</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">More</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown-more">
    <ul class="navbar-sublist" id="#sublist-more">
      <li class="navbar-subitem"><a href="#" class="navbar-sublink">Careers</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-subitem"><a href="#" class="navbar-sublink">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: removing `width:100vw` from `#nav-landing #navbar-list-landing` will fix that, but not sure how that would effect the rest of the layout. The problem is that the `=` is UNDER (think of a web page as layers) the `ul` - therefore, you're actually clicking the `ul`

Comment: alliteratively, move the img+a below the div and add `#nav-open-landing {
  position:relative;
}` - again, this "solves" the issue, but probably causes other ones with your "real code" - I can't test for that

Comment: Thanks! I was actually able to just set the z-index of the #navbar-list-landing to -1

Comment: yeah, z-index works too :p